# hb2dll.auto is set to create but does not work properly

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do) we can assign create to hbm2dll.auto in order to drop all the tables and re-create them but when I assign create to it, and run the application it does not alter some of the tables and shows different Errors in console, as following. I am wondering why it is unable to drop and re-create all the tables.

```
....
ERROR: Table 'mydb.user' doesn't exist
....
ERROR: Table 'animal' already exists
....
Can't create table 'mydb.#sql-43c_6b' (errno: 150)
....
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Comment: do you also get an error if you manually drop the db schema?

Comment: `create` != `create-drop`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```